# Difference between HtmlHelper methods for accessing properties from lambda expression

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, reflection, lambda

I am trying to write my first customer Html Helper extension method following the format

```
public static MvcHtmlString<TModel, TProperty>
    MyHelperFor(this HtmlHelper<TModel> helper, 
    Expression<Func<TModel, TProperty>> expression)
```

And there seem to be several different ways to access the property name and value from the `expression`

```
var body = expression.Body as MemberExpression;
var propertyName = body.Member.Name;
var propertyInfo = typeof(TModel).getProperty(propertyName)
var propertyValue = propertyInfo.GetValue(helper.ViewData.Model);
```

and

```
var metadata = ModelMetadata.FromLambdaExpression(expression, html.ViewData);
var propertyName = metadata.PropertyName;
var propertyValue = metadata.Model;
```

and also

```
TModel model = (TModel)helper.ViewContext.ViewData.ModelMetadata.Model;
TProperty value = expression.Compile().Invoke(model);
```

Can somebody explain the difference between these methods? Are there any situations where one is superior to the others?

Comment: If you inspect the [MVC source code](http://aspnetwebstack.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest) for  `System.Web.Mvc.Html`, you will see that the helpers all use the 2nd variation - `ModelMetadata.FromLambdaExpression(expression, html.ViewData);` so I would assume that is the better approach

Answer (score 10, accepted):

These are 3 different ways of utilizing `Expression<Func<TModel, TProperty>>`. They will all give access to property value. They vary in access to the rest of the expression tree and process cost/efficiency.

Using `expression.Compile().Invoke(model)` executes the expression like a function on your model :: `( u => u.name)`.

```
TModel model = (TModel)helper.ViewContext.ViewData.ModelMetadata.Model;
TProperty value = expression.Compile().Invoke(model);
```

You will get back a property or `list<property>`. It is most efficient when you simply want to execute the Expression and move on.

---

**[ModelMetadata.FromLambdaExpression](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee428393(v=vs.118).aspx)** uses an expression of type `Expression<Func<TParameter, TValue>>` as a `DataDictionary` lookup.

```
var metadata = ModelMetadata.FromLambdaExpression(expression, html.ViewData);
var propertyName = metadata.PropertyName;
var propertyValue = metadata.Model;
```

This approach is more verbose and less efficient, but you have access to property **value** and **name**.

Note that [ModelMetadata](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.modelmetadata_methods(v=vs.118).aspx)  also gives you access to the model's annotated values such as **Validators** and **DisplayName**.

---

**[MemberExpression](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.expressions.memberexpression(v=vs.110).aspx)** uses an expression to access a field / property and it's type.

```
var body = expression.Body as MemberExpression;
var propertyName = body.Member.Name;
var propertyInfo = typeof(TModel).getProperty(propertyName)
var propertyValue = propertyInfo.GetValue(helper.ViewData.Model);
```

This approach is the most verbose and least efficient, but you get have **value**, **name** and **property type**.

**[MemberExpression.Member](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.memberinfo(v=vs.110).aspx)** property give access to **CustomAttributes**